# How do I use Graph theory to determine the minimum amount of moves needed to swap chess pieces?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

On 3x4 chessboard (see below) there are 3 Black knights (B B B) and 3 white knights (WWW), exchange knights in the min # of turns (hint: use graph representation)

B B B -> WWW

0 0 0 -> 0 0 0

0 0 0 -> 0 0 0

WWW -> B B B

Comment: What you want to know? This is a question-answer site, something different from a forum. Take a tour please:http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a $3\times 4$ chessboard, there are at at most three knight moves possible from each field. Thus the graph with fields as vertices and an edge between fields a knight move apart looks quite simple. "Unwrap" the graph:

$$ \begin{matrix}
W_1&\longleftrightarrow&\circ&\longleftrightarrow&W_2\\
\updownarrow&&&&\updownarrow\\
\circ&\longleftrightarrow&B_1&\longleftrightarrow&\circ\\
\updownarrow&&&&\updownarrow\\
\circ&\longleftrightarrow&W_3&\longleftrightarrow&\circ\\
\updownarrow&&&&\updownarrow\\
B_2&\longleftrightarrow&\circ&\longleftrightarrow&B_3\\
\end{matrix}$$

> This makes the solution easier to *see*, but what *is* the actual solution? We see that it is possible to "rotate" the outer two $W$ and $B$ along the outer circle, where each piece must make five moves (so $20$ in total). After that, the "inner" circle of length $6$ can do a similar dance with $6$ moves. This gives us a solution with $26$ moves. Can it be beaten? Yes: Being (a little) casreful, we can perform a cyclic exchange $W_1\to B_1\to W_3\to B_2\to W_1$ with only $10$ moves. Then exchange $W_2$ and $B_3$ with another $10$ moves ... Any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

So based on mathematics, regardless of theorem, the answer appears to be 26 minimum moves. However in practice, I've found it to be 20 is the minimum. My cycle, viewing the board in terms of a chess board:
    1   2   3
A   B   B   B
B
C
D   W   W   W

The solution would be: A1 to B3, D3 to C1, A2 to C3, C1 to A2, B3 to C1, D2 to B3, C1 to D3, A3 to B1, B1 to D2, C3 to B1, A2 to C1, D1 to C3, C3 to A2, B1 to C3, C3 to D1, B3 to A1, C1 to B3, A1 to C2, B3 to A1, C2 to A3.

Towards the end there are a few different routes you can go, but you'll wind up with 20 moves. If anyone has any versions with less, please inform me. Based on *Across the Board: The Mathematics of Chessboard Math* by John Watkins, the solution is 16 minimum. But, I'm unable to decipher his method or terminology and the solution is not entirely clear. Cheers!

Comment: You have not provided sound mathematical reasoning to your answer.